# mlr3 simple question. How do I set fixed hyperparameter values

Tags: mlr3

Hopefully a simple question but incredibly annoying lack of information in the mlr3 book!  So I have a tuned learner (regr.bart) that I want to *simply* set one hyperparameter to a fixed (not tuned) value.  The param in question is 'verbose' which annoyingly is set to TRUE so I get flooded with stupid messages I do not want.  I cannot find a simple example where I can set verbose to FALSE.  Please help.

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(mlr3tuning)

learner = lrn("classif.rpart", cp = to_tune(0.001, 0.1), keep_model = FALSE)

tune(
  method = "random_search",
  task = tsk("pima"),
  learner = learner,
  resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 3),
  measure = msr("classif.ce"),
  term_evals = 10,
  batch_size = 5
)
```

or

```r
library(mlr3tuning)

search_space = ps(
  cp = p_dbl(lower = 0.001, upper = 0.1)
)

learner = lrn("classif.rpart")

learner$param_set$values$keep_model = FALSE

tune(
  method = "random_search",
  task = tsk("pima"),
  learner = learner,
  resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 3),
  measure = msr("classif.ce"),
  term_evals = 10,
  search_space = search_space,
  batch_size = 5
)
```